# Hazelcast No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 0 on standalone process

Tags: serialization, deserialization, hazelcast

Trying to set a HazelCast cluster with tcp-ip enabled on a standalone process.
My class looks like this

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 int    personId;
 String name;
 Person(){};
 //getters and setters
}
```

Hazelcast is loaded as

```
final Config config = createNewConfig(mapName);
HazelcastInstance node = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);`

Config createNewConfig(mapName){
final PersonStore personStore = new PersonStore();
  XmlConfigBuilder configBuilder = new XmlConfigBuilder();


Config config = configBuilder.build();
  config.setClassLoader(LoadAll.class.getClassLoader());
  MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig(mapName);
  MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
  mapStoreConfig.setImplementation(personStore);
  return config;
}
```

and my myhazelcast config has this

```
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member>machine-1</member>
                <member>machine-2</member>
</tcp-ip>
```

Do I need to populate this tag in my xml?

I get this error when a second instance is brought up

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 0
   2275     at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:98)
   2276     at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:39)
   2277     at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41)
   2278     at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:276)
```

Any help is highly appericiated.

Comment: I went through this question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612473/no-dataserializefactory-registered-for-namespace) but I don't want to use my custom serialization but wanted to use default java provided one.

Comment: @noctarius  would you please chime in, I had seen many of your other comments on the similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my problem, I had a pom.xml with hazelcast-wm so I did not have actual hazelcast jar in my bundled jar. Including that fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your own question. Useful if other engineers run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this same "No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 0" error message can also occur in an OSGi environment when you're attempting to use more than one Hazelcast instance within the same VM, but initializing the instances from different bundles.  The reason being that the com.hazelcast.util.ServiceLoader.findHighestReachableClassLoader() method will sometimes pick the wrong class loader during Hazelcast initialization (as it won't always pick the class loader you set on the config), and then it ends up with an empty list of DataSerializerFactory instances (hence causing the error message that it can't find the requested factory with id 0).  The following shows a way to work around that problem by taking advantage of Java's context class loader:

```
private HazelcastInstance createHazelcastInstance() {  

    // Use the following if you're only using the Hazelcast data serializers   
    final ClassLoader classLoader = Hazelcast.class.getClassLoader();

    // Use the following if you have custom data serializers that you need
    // final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    final com.hazelcast.config.Config config = new com.hazelcast.config.Config();
    config.setClassLoader(classLoader);
    final ClassLoader previousContextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    } finally {
        if(previousContextClassLoader != null) {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(previousContextClassLoader);
        }
    }
}
```